# Servlet context is not working

Tags: java, servlets, servletconfig, servletcontextlistener

Please i am trying to store a player object in a HashTable which would then be stored in the ServletContext. When the class is called it is supposed to check if the player (object) is already in the playerList (HashTable) which is stored in the Servlet Context. But each time i call the class it shows that the player(object) isn't in the playerList (HashTable) so it creates a new Player object. I have tried including

```
this.getServletContext().setAttribute("playerList",playerList);
this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().setAttribute("playerList",playerList);
```

BUT it still is not working.

```
public class InitGameServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, JSONException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            Hashtable playerList = (Hashtable)context.getAttribute("playerList");
            String playerid=request.getParameter("id");
            HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
            Player player=null;

            if(!playerList.contains(playerid)) {
                player=new Player(playerid,50);
                playerList.put(playerid, player);                           
                System.out.println("This player wasnt there before so i have put it");
            }
            else {
                player=(Player)playerList.get(playerid);
                System.out.println("This player was there so i have retreived it");
            }
        }
    }
}

@WebListener
public class InitializeGameContext implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        Hashtable<String, Game> gameList = new Hashtable();
        context.setAttribute("gameList", gameList);
        context.log("The game list has beeen loaded...............");
        Hashtable<String, Player> playerList = new Hashtable();
        context.setAttribute("playerList", playerList);
        context.log("The playerList list has beeen loaded..................");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }

}
```

In my web.xml i have

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>web.InitializeGameContext</listener-class>
</listener>
```

EDIT: My complete web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>InitGameServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.whot.servlet.InitGameServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InitGameServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/InitGameServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        3000
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<listener>
    <listener-class>web.InitializeGameContext</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Everything seems okay. Post the rest of your web.xml. Btw, why are you configuring the listener twice once via annotation and then in web.xml as well?

Comment: i have included it in my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

`Hashtable.contains()` Tests if some key maps into the specified ***value*** in this hashtable.

So, within your Servlet at this line

```
if(!playerList.contains(playerid)) {
```

you're actually comparing a ***key*** (playerid) with all the ***values*** (`Player` objects) in your Hashtable. Hence, the match is failing every time.

Your `ServletContext` (as well as its listener) works fine since you're receiving your Hashtable (playerList) on every Servlet call correctly. So, ***to fix the problem*** use `Hashtable.containsKey()` which tests if an object mapping already exists for the specified key.

### Other observations

- Its kind of a misnomer to call a Hashtable a list. Use `playerMap` as an identifier since the table maps a `playerid` kay to a `Player` value object.
- There's no need to both annotate the listener (with `@WebListener`) as well as configure it declaratively in `web.xml` (with `<listener>`). Use only one of the two approaches.
- Unlike `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()` (which sets timeout in secs) `<session-timeout>` sets the timeout interval in mins. So, if you wanted a default session length of 3 mins change `3000` to `3`.